# Choosing a regularization parameter to ensure positive definite-ness.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, hessian-matrix, regularization

This is for use in a nonlinear optimization routine. If I have a Hessian (or Hessian approximation) $H$, that is not guaranteed to be positive semi-definite (PSD), I'd like to find a regularization parameter $\mu$ such that the matrix $\tilde H = H + \mu I$ is positive (semi)definite, but that leaves $\mu$ relatively small. Are there any cheap ways of choosing $\mu$ to do this?

My current solution is to choose $\mu = 10^{-6}$ then check PSD-ness by attempting a Cholesky decomposition and increasing $\mu$ by a factor of $10$ until the Cholesky decomposition succeeds. But this seems inefficient. Are there any best practices for setting the regularization parameter $\mu$ in these situations?

Comment: Gerschgorin disc theorem at least gives you a lower bound on $\lambda_\min(H)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Hessian matrix $\rm H$ is symmetric, we have the following semidefinite program (SDP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{t \geq 0}{\text{minimize}} & t\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm H + t \, \mathrm I \succeq \mathrm O\end{array}$$

The minimum is attained at $t_{\min} := -\lambda_{\min}(\mathrm H)$.

---

[matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [symmetric-matrices](/questions/tagged/symmetric-matrices) [positive-definite](/questions/tagged/positive-definite) [linear-matrix-inequality](/questions/tagged/linear-matrix-inequality) [semidefinite-programming](/questions/tagged/semidefinite-programming)

Comment: This is great and agrees with my intuition that I should be padding $H$ to make all of the eigenvalues positive, but I'd like an efficient way to choose $\mu$ heuristically without solving an SDP or having to compute the largest negative eigenvalue from some other method. Are there useful lower bounds on $\lambda_\text{min}$ that I can compute efficiently?

Comment: @user187815 Well, Gershgorin should be cheaper than solving the SDP. I am aware that Gershgorin was suggested in a comment before I posted my answer (and this comment).